# Ionic Looping JSON Array

Tags: json, angularjs

I'm still make mobile app with Ionic. When i loop data, i stack. I'm using JSON API from http://api.pemiluapi.org/calonpilkada/api/candidates?apiKey=06ec082d057daa3d310b27483cc3962e.

detail.html

```
    <ion-view view-title="Pilih Paslon">
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item class="item-remove-animate item-icon-left" ng-repeat="calon in calonprovinces.data.results.candidates" type="item-text-wrap" href="#/tab/provinces/{{calon.dob}}">
       <i class="icon ion-ios-location"></i>
        <h2>{{calon}}</h2>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

controller.php

```
.controller('DetailCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, $http) {

   $http.get('http://api.pemiluapi.org/calonpilkada/api/candidates?apiKey=06ec082d057daa3d310b27483cc3962e')
       .then(function(rest){
          $scope.calonprovinces = rest.data;  
          //alert(rest.data);              
        });

})
```

I want to display this value:

"paslon":[{"kind":"CALON","nama":"Ridwan Mukti","jk":"L","pob":"Lubuk Linggau","dob":"1963-05-21","alamat":"PKB, Hanura, PKPI, Nasdem","pekerjaan":"Wiraswasta","status":"1"},{"kind":"WAKIL","nama":"Rohidin Mersyah","jk":"L","pob":"Manna","dob":"1970-01-09","alamat":"PKB, Hanura, PKPI, Nasdem","pekerjaan":"Wakil Bupati Kabupaten Bengkulu Selatan","status":"1"}]

But i can't found the solution. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var app = angular.module("App", []);
app.controller("Ctrl", function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('http://api.pemiluapi.org/calonpilkada/api/candidates?apiKey=06ec082d057daa3d310b27483cc3962e').then(function(rest) {
    $scope.calonprovinces = rest.data;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="App" ng-controller="Ctrl">
<div ng-repeat="calon in calonprovinces.data.results.candidates">
  <h2>{{calon.paslon[0].nama}}</h2>
  {{calon.paslon}}
</div>
</body>
```